# Method "add a job" is never awaited

Tags: nestjs

Method this.aQueue.add(*args) which returns an job instance is endlessly awaited. After receiving and deserializing data i try to get a job instance in the method RequestService.sendData of app.service.ts module, but can't do it and the rest of code is not running

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job, Queue } from 'bull';
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { RequestScheme, ResponseScheme } from './app.schemes';
 
 
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('request') private requestQueue: Queue
  ){}
 
   async sendData(data: RequestScheme): Promise<ResponseScheme> {
    let responseData: ResponseScheme
    data = plainToClass(RequestScheme, data)
    console.log("data in controller", data) // data is deserialized as i expect
 
    const jobInstance = await this.requestQueue.add(
      'request', data, { delay: data.wait }
    ) // this method is running and never awaited
 
    console.log(`Job: ${jobInstance}`)
 
    async function setJobData(jobInstance: Job){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.requestQueue.on('completed', function(job: Job, result: ResponseScheme, error){
        if (jobInstance.id == job.id) {
          responseData = result
          job.remove()
          resolve(result)
        }
        if (error) reject(error)
      })
    })}
    
    await setJobData(jobInstance)
    return responseData
   }
  }
```

app.processor.ts

```
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { 
  Processor, 
  Process, 
  OnQueueActive,
  OnQueueCompleted
} from '@nestjs/bull';
import { ResponseScheme } from './app.schemes';
 
@Processor('request')
export class RequestConsumer {
 
  @Process('request')
  async process_request(job: Job){
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} proceed`)
  }
 
  @OnQueueActive()
  onActive(job: Job){
    console.log(`Data ${job.data} were sended`)
  }
 
  @OnQueueCompleted()
  onComplete(job: Job){
    const response = new ResponseScheme()
    response.answer = job.data.answer
    return response
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Global, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { RequestController } from './app.controller';
import { RequestService } from './app.service';
import { RequestConsumer } from './app.processor';
 
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        maxRetriesPerRequest: null
      }
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'request'
    })
  ],
  controllers: [RequestController],
  providers: [
    RequestService
  ],
  exports: [
    RequestService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: RequestConsumer){}
}
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { Body, Controller, Get, HttpException, HttpStatus, Post, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestService } from './app.service';
import { RequestScheme, ResponseScheme } from './app.schemes';
 
@Controller('request')
export class RequestController {
  constructor(private readonly requestService: RequestService) {}
 
  @Get()//this works good
  about(): string{
    return "Hello! This is the request"
  }
 
  @Post()
  async getHello(@Body() data: RequestScheme): Promise<ResponseScheme> {
    console.log("POST", "data", data) //client data, good as it's expected
    let responseData: ResponseScheme
    responseData = await this.requestService.sendData(data)
    return responseData
  }
}
```

Based on manual[https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues] this method is standard for nestjs.

```
const job = await this.audioQueue.add(
  {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  { lifo: true },
);
```

But my variant is running endlessly - it doesn’t matter what data I have in wait (string or number):

```
const jobInstance = await this.requestQueue.add(
      'request', data, { delay: data.wait }
    )
```

Also, i tried to get hardcode data from RequestService.sendData by hidding "add a job" method, and it works. But i need to add a job.

Answer (score 0):

Oooookay. And what do you want to achieve with this setup? :)

Don't get me wrong but from my place it looks as if you were dispatching a job from controller, to be processed by a processor that doesn't do anything except for console.logging, but controller needs to wait until the job is done and returns some data.

Also, the code from inside a promise:

```js
        if (jobInstance.id == job.id) {
          responseData = result
          job.remove()
          resolve(result)
        }
```

is supposed to change the `responseData` which is outside of its scope, and rather inaccessible from there, as that promise is not even executed in the context of the `sendData`, but run from within another promise function, also this is never defined, as your processor returns nothing. Plus, `job.remove()` is a promise itself.

Also you have a `if-else` clause, that says:

1. if `jobInstance.id` is equal-ish to `job.id`, then do sth,
2. in other case if we have an error, then reject,
3. in all other cases (`jobInstance.id` isn't equal-ish to `job.id`, but there's no error) - do nothing. Wait. Wait. Wait. Just wait ;)

Also a promise function with `async` inside of an `async` function that's something that might lead to many weird stuff going on. Besides, when you do `async function xyz(...) { this.requestQueue...}`, what do you mean by `this`?

---

If your intention was to withhold controller until job is finished, then mutate some data inside of the controller method, to display it to the end-user, then it's absolutely not the way. But I can't determine if that was actually your intention, so I don't know if that's the direction you're interested in :)

Comment: Hello! Good morning, good evening, good night! Thank you for your response. Sorry, i can't upvote your answer yet, because my reputation level is too low

Comment: Relying what i mean when i declare setJobData. Here I have to wrap the event handler function (when queue listens 'completed' job event) in a new async function setJobData because handler function runs asynchronic.

Comment: The function setJobData originally should be to return a mutated data as i need. But for now i decided just to assign the mutated data as value to responseData variabale. I've not test setJobData yet, but responseData variable is visible as i check it in VCode

Comment: Even if i rewrite this service hidding setJobData and just return some hardcode data, like this:

Comment: just example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-lvpofq?file=src%2Fapp.service.ts&terminal=start

Comment: Then i still can't wait for this method this.requestQueue.add to complete

Comment: Let's look at the module app.module.ts.

Comment: Let's assume that i don't need to do much with the data, but just wait for a timeout to slightly change just the data structure itself. But this can be done in the onComplete method that is implemented there, so I simply display the job id to the console in the process_request method

Comment: Since method onComplete runs when job successfully completed with a result, then i expect that handler function in setJobData method return this data. May be i miss something, but i dunno, because i'm just learning nestjs.

Comment: !!Oh I catch you, i see "this" - it is not a way to link at the service class instance inside an async function, which was declared as a separate function in service method sendData. Thanks!